# How to change the size of monitor in "Customize your display" (NOT RESOLUTION)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a multi-monitor setup which looks like this:

[image]

The resolutions are correct (all are 1080p), but the sizes are incorrect and I can't seem to find where to change the size (so the cursor will jump to the correct position). In reality the size difference between monitor 1 and 2 are this:

[image]

This is bad because the mouse pointer then jumps, example: if you move from left edge of screen one(1) to screen two(2) (vertically up), the cursor jumps 15 cm to the left, this is unwanted behaviour.

How can I change the screen size in Windows to reflect the real size of my screens (**NOT THE SCREEN RESOLUTION!**) ?

I'm using Windows 10 but would need to know this for Windows 7 too if possible.

Comment: There's no way to differentiate. It can only go on resolution, size is simply not taken into account. If you move from 'column' 123 on one screen, that's where you will arrive on the other, wherever it may be in space.

Comment: Ah that is so unfortunate :(